# drupal 7 display user info for current user

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, relationship, profile

I need to display `name, role, photo` of current user. 
I'm use views,  in Advanced settings add Contextual filters select Content: Author uid and in settings of it select Provide default value ,in type selectbox choose User ID from logged in user. 
But in fields i haven't field 'user:name'.
If i create relationship `content : author` , user name will be displayed, but only for users, that published node.
At the end, i want see like this

```
Hello, SmithJN
Role: Authorised user
Photo: [photo]
```

Answer (score 3):

When you create the view, at the very first screen, you have the option to select the entity type on which you want to create the view. (thank J.Reynolds)

Then in Fields add Field Name, Role, Image In Fileter Criteria add filter User : current

It's all !